# Prob. 2, Sec. 18 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: A necessary and sufficient condition for the image of a limit point to be a limit point?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Here's Prob. 2, Sec. 18 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Suppose that $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous. If $x$ is a limit point of the subset $A$ of $X$, is it necessarily true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

I know that the answer is no.

For example, let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $$f(x) \colon= 1 \ \mbox{ for all } \ x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Then the point $x = 0$ is a limit point of the subset $S$ of the domain space $\mathbb{R}$, where  $$S \colon= \left\{ \ \frac 1 n \ \colon \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ \right\}.$$

Now my question is as follows:

> Can we impose any necessary and / or sufficient condition(s) on the continuous map $f \colon X \to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, such that if a point $x$ is a limit point of a subset $A$ of $X$, then the point $f(x)$ should also be a limit point of the subset $f(A)$ of $Y$?

Comment: If $f(A)$ is closed, done.