# Prob. 2, Sec. 18, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: The continuous image of a limit point need not be a limit point

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here is Prob. 2, Sec. 18, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Suppose that $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous. If $x$ is a limit point of the subset $A$ of $X$, is it necessarily true that $f(x)$ is a limit point of $f(A)$?

Here $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces.

My answer is no. For example, let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any constant function. Then although $0$ is a limit point of the set of positive real numbers, the image set under $f$ of the set of positive real numbers has no limit point.

Now my question is, is there a necessary and / or sufficient condition that will gaurantee that the answer to the above question is always yes?

If $Y$ has the discrete topology, then the answer is always no for any function $f \colon X \to Y$, irrespective of whether or not $f$ is continuous. Am I right?

Comment: If $f$ is also one-to-one, then the answer is yes. (For a nbhd $U$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is a nbhd of $x$, meeting $A$ at points other than $x$, which map to points of $U$ other than $f(x)$.) Off the top of my head I don't know a necessary condition.

Comment: Would $f$ being an open map be sufficient? I think it would.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628867/prob-2-sec-18-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-a-necessary-and-sufficient-condit. (Asked by the same person, too.)

Comment: No, being an open map is not sufficient. If $Y$ has the discrete topology every map $X \to Y$ is open, including the constant map. Then $f(x)$ is in the closure of $f(A)$, but not a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the doubling of $\mathbb{N}$, which is $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$, where $\{0,1\}$ has the indiscrete (trivial) topology.

Define $p: X \to \mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$ the "projection" ($p(x,i) = (x,0)$ which is open and continuous and has fibres of size $2$. But $(0,1)$ is a limit point of $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$ while $p(0,1) = (0,0)$ is not a limit of $\mathbb{N} \times \{0\}$ (which is discrete).